# Staying stationary in an inertial body

Tags: classical-mechanics

Consider the following example; a person standing in a train
 moving at constant velocity.
Why does the person remain stationary in the train's reference frame? ie why does the person move with the train? In other words why does the person move at a constant velocity with the train!
Thoughts 
Static friction but what force is it balancing?
What if the person is hovering it is clear that they will move with the train as they are being pushed by the moving air particles.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_invariance. Galilean invariance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The laws of motion apply the same way in all *inertial frames*. 
Consider a train which is initially at rest, then accelerates for a certain time period and finally moves with a constant velocity. Now, consider a passenger in the train.

**In the ground frame:** When the train is at rest there is no net external horizontal force on the passenger, therefore the passenger remains in his state of rest. As the train accelerates, static friction acts on the passenger to prevent relative motion and passenger accelerates with the train. When the train stops accelerating, static friction again becomes zero, i.e. no net external force in the horizontal direction acts on the passenger and he therefore moves with the acquired constant velocity. Now if the person were to start hovering, the net external force in the horizontal direction on him would be zero he would continue his state of motion. *Force is required for acceleration, not for maintaining a constant velocity.*

Try reading this: https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/forces-newtons-laws/newtons-laws-of-motion/a/what-is-newtons-first-law